# negation condition logic; negation

Tags: javascript, negation

Could you help me to invert this condition in javascript?

```
(this.startingNode.isAdaptive && this.startingNode.studentAssessment.isNotCompleted && this.user.isStudentLike) || this.isFinalAssessment
```

Comment: Put parentheses around the whole thing and then put `!` in front of that.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!` in front of it and wrap it in brackets `()`.

Like this:

`!((this.startingNode.isAdaptive && this.startingNode.studentAssessment.isNotCompleted && this.user.isStudentLike) || this.isFinalAssessment)`